# How much clearance does my GPU fan need?

Tags: graphics-card, gpu, fan

I just installed a second nVidia GTX 660 in my desktop. Both cards are connected to the PCIe x16 slots. I am also going to be installing a small RAID card in the system also.

Originally I was sure the RAID card would fit and leave plenty of room for the 2 intake fans for GPU #1. After taking a good look at the current configuration of the cards and where the RAID card will be installed I am not sure there is enough clearance for the fans.

Without accurately measuring the gap since I still wait on the RAID card in the mail, I would say the gap wont be more then 1/4" or so. I mean it looks tight.

Is that going to cause major issues? I does not look like it will touch the fans, just get really close. Like I said though I am not sure since I have received the RAID card in the mail yet.

These are the intake fans by the way not the exhaust fans as far I can tell. There is a vent in the rear of the card for exhaust.

Any idea if this is okay?

Comment: You'll get less airflow and it'll be nosier if the fan is blocked.